# Elasticsearch keyword length more than 6

Tags: elasticsearch

I actually want to aggregate all the values of the a field in my index whose length is greater than 6 in some date range.

I could fetch all values of the field, grouped by that keyword. Now, i want to add the condition to check if the keyword length is more than 6 or not.
Here is the query, till where I could come up with.

```
"size": 0, 
 "aggs": {
  "range":{
    "date_range": {
     "field": "timestamp",
     "ranges": [
       {
         "from": "now-1d/d",
         "to": "now"
       }
     ]
   },
   "aggs": {
     "group_by_name":{
       "terms": {
         "field": "name.keyword",
         "size": 100
       } 
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can did using simple painless script. check out the docs [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

```
 {
    "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "range": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": "now-1d/d",
                "to": "now"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_name": {
              "terms": {
                "script": {
                  "source": """
                        if (doc['name.keyword'].value.toString().length() > 6) {
                          return doc['name.keyword'].value;
                        }
                        """,
                  "lang": "painless"
                },
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

}
```